# How to use square dagger-compiler for "compile-only" using gradle?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, dagger

Currently I have my dagger dependencies declared like this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
```

I don't want dagger-compiler to be included to my Android apk since it also adds Guava dependency, which is big and break Android 65K limit for our app.

I saw that in maven projects dagger-compiler is added as "provided", but I failed to find anything similar for gradle android build.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a `provided` keyword:

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
```

Heres a sample build.gradle: [volley-examples](https://github.com/marcoRS/volley-examples/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

Comment: if i use this solution i still get the runteimeException: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class com.example.testapp.MainModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.  I am not able to get this to run. AS 0.9.2 android plugin 0.14.1

Comment: One of your dependencies could be interfering with the Dagger code generation. That's happened to me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The provided scope is supported in Android-Gradle/Android Studio. You can get at it through the UI in Project Structure > Dependencies, or you can use the `provided` keyword instead of `compile` in your build files if you want to edit them by hand.